# Proving for onto. For the set where n belong to non negative integers with n mod 3 = 1 and the second set of all positive integers.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Proving for onto. For the set where n belong to non negative integers with $n \mod 3 = 1$ and the second set of all positive integers.

Sorry I couldn't fit all of the question in the title. The function that links the two sets is $F(x)= 2x-3$ which is the positive integers set to the first one described in the title. I understand to solve for $y$ but am confused on the next step

Comment: Please don't try to put the whole question in the title.  The title is for a title, and the question is for a question.